# Output Javascript variable when page loads through AJAX

Tags: javascript, ajax

I have a quiz where each question reloads in a div using AJAX rather than refreshing the entire page.

I have a variable `quizScore` which holds the score the user has.

On the last button press, the page `questionendQuiz.php` is loaded into my `quizWrapper`.

I want to output the score into a span called `scoreout`

```
<span id="scoreOut"></span>
```

I tried using `getElementById`

```
document.getElementById("scoreout").value = quizScore;
```

The problem is, this doesn't run when the page is loaded in through AJAX. So I tried binding it to the success of the AJAX page loading:

```
$( document ).ajaxComplete(function( event,request, settings ) {
  document.getElementById("scoreout").value = quizScore;  
});
```

So that when the page with that script on is run it should run and output the score, but it doesn't seem to work.

You can see the site here: http://fh80.student.eda.kent.ac.uk/fyp-assets/quiz/quiz.php

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`.value` is for form elements like `<input>` tags.  You should use `.innerHTML` for a div or span or other type of HTML element.

```
document.getElementById("scoreout").innerHTML = quizScore;
```

As for the timing issue, you just need to execute this statement AFTER the `scoreout` DOM object is in the page and the `quizScore` is at its current value.  This doesn't permanently bind the value of `quizScore` to the DOM element, it's just a one time transfer of the value.  You will have to rerun this statement anytime you want to display the newly changed score.

If you are updating this score via an ajax call, you can either use `.ajaxComplete()` as you are doing to update the score after any ajax call completes or you can update the score display in your code right after you calculate the newly updated score (wherever that is in your code).

Answer (score 0):

I looked at your website. In order to make it work, you should change your `nextQuestion` function and add `if(buttonID ...` like this:

```
if (xmlhttp.readyState==4 && xmlhttp.status==200)
{
    document.getElementById("quizWrapper").innerHTML=xmlhttp.responseText;
    if (buttonID == "question_endQuiz") {
        document.getElementById("scoreOut").innerHTML = quizScore;
    }
}
```

Also it should be "scoreOut" instead of "scoreout" because javascript is case-sensitive.